# Removing old boot images when one in use is only partially installed

Tags: boot, apt

I'm trying to update my kernel and after I made an attempt, it partially installed.  Now, when I restart nothing works properly.

I've looked at previous questions, and posted my own that hasn't recieved an answer.

Basically I need to uninstall old kernels to make space for the 'sudo apt-get install -f' to work. But nothing I do makes any difference.

I need to free up space some how. I tried gparted, but it won't let me make the necessary changes. How do I delete old kernal images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the following carefully, and don't proceed unless you understand the instructions and the affects of you not performing this successfully.

You can determine your currently loaded kernel and version by using `uname -a`.

Your computer has files under `/boot/` that help your computer start up.  Once it has loaded these files, it will require files in `/lib/modules/<kernel.version>/`.

So, let's say you've decided that you only want 3.14 kernel.  Let's say you have a 3.12 version you would like to remove.

1. Remove the files from `/boot/`

   - `ls /boot/ | grep 3.12`
   - Verify the files listed
   - `rm -rf /boot/*3.12*`
2. Remove associated kernel modules

   - `ls /lib/modules/ | grep 3.12`
   - Verify the files listed
   - `rm -rf /lib/modules/*3.12*`

You can use `df -h` before and after to see the free space available on each of your mounted partitions.

Comment: I'm not completely sure which kernal I'm using. They are all 3.13.0 with a dash -31 or -41 or -43 etc.

Comment: `uname -a` will tell you your current kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

To view which kernel you have loaded type:

uname -r

To view which kernel versions you have installed type:

dpkg -l | grep linux-image-

To remove them:

sudo apt-get --purge autoremove linux-image--generic

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ sudo -i
# OLDCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
# CURKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
# LINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
# METALINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
# OLDKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $LINUXPKG |grep -vE $METALINUXPKG|grep -v $CURKERNEL)
# apt-get remove --purge $OLDCONF
# apt-get remove --purge $OLDKERNELS
# apt-get autoremove
# apt-get clean
```

**Note:** *$ = user prompt. # = root prompt.*